# how to fetch all the houskeepers name & the sum of 1bed,2 bed & total_work_time at once from the selected date?

Tags: mysql, sql

there are 2 table tbl_hk and tbl_hk_work:

1. tbl_hk:hk_id(pk), hk_name
2. tbl_hk_work:hk_work_id, hk_id(fk), hk_work_date, hk_work_1bed, hk_work_2bed, hk_work_time

Now the problem is I want to fetch all housekeepers name, the sum of 1bed, 2 bed and total work hours from the date that provided from the user

Right now I have the one query which is working great but it only fetches only 1 housekeeper data at a time.

```
select t2.hk_name, sum(hk_work_1bed), sum(hk_work_2bed), sum(hk_work_time_decimal)
from tbl_hk_work t1 inner join
     tbl_hk t2
     on t2.hk_id = t1.hk_id
 where hk_work_date between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-30' and t2.hk_id='1'
 group by t2.hk_name"
```

This is the Data I'm getting it right now:

```
hk_name   sum(hk_work_1bed)   sum(hk_work_2bed)   sum(hk_work_time_decimal)
Veronica  12                  25                  28.86
```

This is the Data what is what I expect:

```
hk_name   sum(hk_work_1bed)   sum(hk_work_2bed)   sum(hk_work_time_decimal)
Veronica  12                  25                  28.86
Carmen    10                  16                  27.31
Sofia     08                  11                  20.46
Amanda    05                  09                  17.19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the extra filter in the `where` clause:

```
select t2.hk_name, sum(hk_work_1bed), sum(hk_work_2bed), sum(hk_work_time_decimal)
from tbl_hk_work t1 inner join
     tbl_hk t2
     on t2.hk_id = t1.hk_id
where hk_work_date between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-30' 
group by t2.hk_name;
```

That is, remove `t2.hk_id = '1'`.

Comment: ok, thanks, it worked really appreciate it & I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue is the "and t2.hk_id='1'" in the where clause.